# Term for how anxiety makes people think abnormally?

Tags: emotion, terminology, abnormal-psychology, clinical-psychology, anxiety

For a paper I'm writing, I want to make a point about how anxiety changes the way people think - i.e., the same person in the same situation might think differently depending on whether or not they are anxious.

The problem is that I'm not sure what search term to use to find papers that may be relevant, so I was just wondering if anyone else knows.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg Ah great, thanks! I eventually stumbled upon executive functions - "Impulse control, Emotional Control, Flexible Thinking, Working Memory, Self-Monitoring, Planning and Prioritizing, Task Initiation, and Organization" but I think cognitive distortions makes more sense in this context.

Answer (score 3):

A general term is [cognitive distortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion):

> ... an exaggerated or irrational thought pattern involved in the onset
> or perpetuation of psychopathological states, such as depression and
> anxiety.

Not sure if there are more emotion-specific terms.

Answer (score 2):

I think 'cognitive distortion' is a good one, like @Arnon Weinberg mentioned.

You will probably also find some useful papers with ''anxiety''+''cognitive bias''.
E.g. this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S1364-6613(97)01092-9)

> The existence of cognitive biases in anxiety is now well established,
> and we summarize evidence demonstrating attentional vigilance to cues
> associated with threat, pessimistic interpretation of ambiguous items
> and an increased perception of the likelihood of occurrence of
> negative events.

Bias you can further split up in ''attentional bias'' or ''memory bias''.